# landscape j2me game with WTK emulator

Tags: java-me, landscape, java-wireless-toolkit

I am working on a landscape java game and using Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01 as emulator.

I am able to see landscape image of the game while using emulator but still the emulator is positioned in portrait mode. This makes it difficult to debug and review the project.

Is there any way to get the proper view for landscape game Wireless Toolkit?